# Is there a way to cancel a blocking `MPI_Probe` call?

Tags: mpi

The `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Isend` operations return an `MPI_Request` that can be later marked as cancelled with `MPI_Cancel`. Is there a similar mechanism for blocking `MPI_Probe` and `MPI_Mprobe` ?

The context of the question is the latest implementation of [Boost.MPI request handlers](https://github.com/boostorg/mpi/blob/0038915c4426ec17f02d82284141a73aee9dd6a0/include/boost/mpi/detail/request_handlers.hpp#L128) using Probe.

---

**EDIT** - Here is an example of how an hypothetical `MPI_Probecancel` could be used:

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <future>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

// Executed in a thread
void async_cancel(MPI_Probe *probe)
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

  int res = MPI_Probecancel(probe);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int provided;
  MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);

  if (rank == 0)
  {
    // A handle to the probe (similar to a request)
    MPI_Probe probe;

    // Start a thread
    // `probe` will be filled with the next call, pretty ugly
    // Ideally, this should be done in two steps like MPI_Irecv, MPI_Wait
    auto res = std::async(std::launch::async, &async_cancel, &probe);

    MPI_Message message;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_MProbe(1, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &message, &status, &probe);

    if (!probe.cancelled)
    {
        int buffer;
        MPI_Mrecv(&buffer, 1, MPI_INT, &message, &status);
    }
  }
  else
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the premise / nomenclature of your question is wrong. It is the **nonblocking** calls. `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Isend` which return a request object that you may cancel. For these calls, you cancel the **local operation**.

`MPI_Probe` and `MPI_Mprobe` are in fact **blocking**. You cannot possibly cancel these operations in the sense that control flow will only leave *when* a message is available.

On the other hand, `MPI_Iprobe` and `MPI_Improbe` are **nonblocking**, meaning they always complete immediately, telling you *whether* a message is available.

For neither kind of  probe call, there is any kind of local state left after the completion. So there is nothing that could be cancelled locally after the functions return.

That said, if a probe tells you that a message is available, you should definitely receive it. Otherwise a send operation may bock and you would leak resources on all side. But that's just a receive operation.

Edit: Regarding your idea to cancel a ongoing local `MPI_Probe` in a concurrent thread: This is not directly supported.

Theoretically, you could emulate this on a conforming implementation with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPE` by running the probe on `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` and send a message to the same rank from the other thread. That, of course, has the consequence that you change must probe on message from any incoming rank.

Realistically, if you have to do this, you would probably just use a loop like `while(!cancelled) MPI_Iprobe();`.

That said, I would again question the scenario: How would another thread on your rank suddenly know to cancel a local `MPI_Probe` operation? It would probably have to be based on information received from a remote rank - in which case that would be covered by actually being able to receive information from it, i.e. the actual Probe would complete.

Maybe for some high-level abstraction it makes some sense to offer a local cancel, but in an actual practical situation I would believe you could design a idiomatic pattern without needing this.

Comment: Thanks @Zulan, I edited the question to fix the nomenclature issue (mixing C and Boost.MPI APIs).

Comment: *"You cannot possibly cancel these operations in the sense that control flow will only leave when a message is available"*. Should'nt this be considered a design issue? For the sequence `MPI_Irecv` - `MPI_Wait` we have a cancel option, but for `MPI_Mprobe` - `MPI_Mrecv` we don't?

Comment: What do you think the semantics of cancelling a probe should mean?

Comment: Maybe just "stop probing"? If I have a thread that calls `MPI_Mprobe`,  `MPI_Mrecv` in a loop, how can I exit the thread it if I am locked in `MPI_Mprobe` without a way to cancel the probing from the main thread? Maybe not the typical use case though...

Comment: So which thread/process is going to invoke the imaginary `MPI_Probecancel` while the thread in question is stuck in `MPI_(M)probe`?

Comment: I try to write an example and now I see you point :-).  I edited the question to show how it could work with additional parameter to `MPI_(M)probe`.

Comment: @Samuel I try to address your edit in an edit to my answer.

Comment: Regarding the use case, it's an MPMD app with say 2 processes (RPC client and server), server listening for commands, client listening for (server) events in an ancillary thread. User interact with the client and can `quit()` the client to end the app. I guess `quit()` can not be local but needs to send a `quit` command to the server that in turn will send a `quit` event to unlock the MPI_Probe and exit the event loop thread nicely.